# Pip error when trying to run pip command from virtualenv on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I have my virtualenv created in ~/Desktop/env. During install it states that pip was installed successfully, along with setuptools and wheel. After activation I attempted to install a module in my virtualenv using pip but was given this error:

```
File "/Users/myname/Desktop/hello/env_test/bin/pip3.7", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

Looking in the bin folder there are three pips - pip, pip3, and pip3.7. Running any of these commands gives me the error above.

Can anyone help me out here? pip3 works just fine outside of the virtual environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and re-installing pip (not upgrading) solved the problem on Mac OS: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with newer version of pip after 20.0.0 release https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7620

Suggested fix

```
pip install -U pip
```

**NOTE:** For anyone having this is issue in their CI try cleaning caches

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. A simple work around worked for me.
For `python3`, in the virtualenv, when running pip commands, instead of directly using `pip`, use `python3 -m pip`.

For example, use:

```
python3 -m pip install xx
```

instead of

```
pip install xx
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you please post the commands you are issuing to install the environment? 
I can suggest you to install `pipenv` and then try with:

```
pipenv install
pipenv shell
```